# Как вернуть окно InteliJ IDEA в начальное состояние?

Tags: intellij-idea, настройки

Из состояния номер 1 перевести в состояние номер 2.

См. скриншоты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> помогает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вкладка View -> Tool Windows -> Project или Alt+1

Answer (score 0):

Возможно `View` -> `Tool Buttons`.